# playing Random sounds on a soundboard app

Tags: random, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, xcode4.5, audio-player

I have been trying to create a app that when I press a button it plays a sound but then when I press the same button again it plays a different sound I don't mind if it plays it totally random all the time or if it plays a different sound a time but the same order every time hope this make sense guys

Here's all the code I have:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController



@class AVAudioPlayer;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)PlayRandomSound;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *soundPlayer;




@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize soundPlayer = _soundPlayer;


-(IBAction)PlayRandomSound{

    int randomNumber = arc4random() % 8 + 1;

    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound%02d", randomNumber] ofType:@"mp3"]];


    _soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];

    [_soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_soundPlayer play];


    NSLog(@"randomNumber is %d", randomNumber);
    NSLog(@"tmpFilename is %@", soundURL);
}
```

Here the errors I have in images

[image]

[image]

I have also inserted the AVFoundation.Framework and AudioToolbox.Frame

Comment: please i cant seem to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many problems with this. It's hard to answer your actual question because you have lots of little problems that are getting in the way.

To give you some help:

this is incorrect:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@class AVAudioPlayer;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

As the image you have posted, even Xcode is trying to help you. The `@class` forward declaration is in the wrong place. Try putting it just after the `#import` statements. Because of this your soundplayer isn't being created properly and you are getting other warnings.

You need to fix all the errors and then all the warnings and keep doing this until it builds cleanly.

Comment: Read it again - I've told you what to move to where to help you get started.

Comment: i known its just one bit of code i need can you please just help me this once my friend @Abizern

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. I've told you what to do. If you are asking me to show you the exact way it should be written instead of just telling you to move the @class declaration until it is just below the #import statement that isn't going to help much as it is just an example of one thing that is wrong. Once you do that and compile it you'll probably get different errors. Then what are you going to do? As was commented in your other question - you need to get a better grasp of the fundamentals.