# Random sound plays when pressing a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [playing Random sounds on a soundboard app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513525/playing-random-sounds-on-a-soundboard-app)

I'm trying to make an app that when I press a button it plays a random sound each time. I have 20 sounds altogether but the problem is I'm not the best coder and could really do with some help on this.

First question: is this possible?

Second question: do you have any code that work for this?

my question was edited please note i wasn't this rude when i typed this out

Comment: #1: Yes it is possible, #2: Use google.

Comment: Please try something before you post a question. It is possible, and really isn't that difficult. But before you tell us to do it, what you need to try yourself. If you have tried, don't forget about: whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @AceLegend the above link is my question thats what i have tried and been trying for several days please can you??

Comment: @PaulR Thats my other question??

Comment: He linked it as a duplicate because you started a second question with less information than the first question. The reason you're probably not getting any answers to your first question is that there's a lot wrong with your code. It makes it hard to give you a concise answer. Not being rude when I say it, but you probably should take a step back and go read Apple's getting started docs. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: ok guys i will read it thanks for you advice :)

Comment: There must be some random function

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in storyboard. Add a Button to it, which calls a routine. 
Let this routine get a random number (arc4random) and use a switch
to play the song.

Comment: This is basic programming. Advise search on youtube for tutorials of "geekylemon". This guy makes good tutorials for beginners.